# Sqlite: Rename columns and datatype

Tags: c#, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using a SQLite database. Since drop/rename/reorder columns are not supported in SQLite (using alter table commands), I am writing customized methods for the following tasks: (taking backup of existing table, then creating a new table with matching requirements and so on..) which is described in several other threads.

The following are the DB operations:
DROP columns
RENAME (columns and datatype)
ADD columns
REORDER columns.

I am wondering in what order should these operations be done? My confusion is mainly around whether drop should come before rename columns or the other way?

Also I need some pointers on how to rename columns including datatype and moving data around?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a backup of your database in case something goes wrong during the following instructions.

The order of operations should be `CREATE newtable`, `INSERT INTO newtable`, `DROP oldtable`.

Create a new table with the correct column names and datatypes for each column. Then just do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO new_table(columns, ...)
(SELECT columns, ...
FROM old_table)
```

You may need to perform casts on different datatypes if the new datatype isn't directly compatible with the old datatype.

You will need to make sure that the columns you select from your old table are in the same order as defined by the columns in your new table in your `INSERT INTO` statement.

After data is inserted into your new table, you can then verify that all data has been inserted correctly. Be sure to update any foreign key references in your other tables to avoid any issues with foreign key constraints.

Then you can drop the old table and rename the new table to the name of your old table:

```
DROP old_table;
ALTER TABLE new_table_name RENAME TO old_table_name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Can you elaborate on "You may need to perform casts on different datatypes if the new datatype isn't directly compatible with the old datatype.". How to do it in SQL statements? Should this be done in the Insert Into command? If so, how to do it?

Comment: The syntax for casting would be something like `cast(col as type)` where `col` is the column and `type` is a SQL type such as real, int, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to implement Rename. I have so far implemented Drop, Rename, Add and reorder columns. However I am running some tests to find out in what order should these routines be called? Should drop column be called first always? Is the order DROP RENAME ADD REORDER columns? Any thoughts?

Comment: I was mainly referring to making sure that your insert statement columns align with your old table's columns. You just want to be sure that rows are inserted with the proper column mapping. You can reorder your columns any way that you like. Just be sure that x maps to x, y maps to y, etc.

Comment: Sorry to bother you further but I think there was a miscommunication. I am not referring to the order in which columns are renamed and inserted but the order in which the routines DROP columns RENAME columns ADD columns and REORDER columns should be called. This thread talks about rename only, however I have other routines implemented and was wondering if there's a recommended order to call these routines. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the order of operations. No need to do anything complicated with the new table schema. Just make sure that it includes the new columns and removes old columns that aren't needed. Also, the order of which you add columns is arbitrary.